# What are some killer Linux applications?

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Must-Have” Linux Software](https://superuser.com/questions/1430/must-have-linux-software)

I want to know which program do you like in Linux very much, for me, I like bash, amarok,....etc.

One per answer please.

Comment: wiki please ...

Comment: really should be wiki, but I have a sneaking suspicion it's a dupe anyway :)

Comment: Wondering if I should start a best of best lists!

Comment: some similar threads http://superuser.com/questions/6245/must-have-kde-application http://superuser.com/questions/5439/must-have-launcher-applications and of course, dupe http://superuser.com/questions/1430/must-have-linux-software

Comment: "bash, amarok, ...etc". You rock, dude!

Comment: @will "Must-Read" superuser lists? ;)

Comment: Duplicate: Voted to close.

Answer (score 4):

[Kill](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl_kill.htm) works fine for me!

Answer (score 2):

Killer? [xkill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xkill) is pretty efficient at killing!
Seriously, though, Gnome-Do. I wish I had something of that calibre on windows, launchy doesn't come close, and while executor and a bit of python has similar featuresets, it's not as slick at all.

Comment: :D yeah xkill is the best app :D killer app :D

Answer (score 1):

gvim, of course

Answer (score 0):

Wine, allows me to retain a video gaming habit until those big companies start supporting linux ;)